# Need help extracting Org Name, Name, phone and email from text file with no ID tags

Tags: python

I have a large text file with data that is mostly symmetrical in the data placement. I want to pull Organization Name, First Name, Last Name, Phone number (there are two types of possibilities here it could be with just 10 digits or country code+phonenumber), email id from the text file.

I searched SO most of it points to Regular expression for email ID but I want more data than just email id.

This is how the data set looks like there are 10,000s of these

New

Edit |
University Of Texas Md Anderson Cancer Center
TX
lastName, firstName
1231231234
mailid@mdanderson.org
owner
B
86.95
User1,User 2,User 3
CP
E-Seminar Event
Q3FY19-eSeminar-TRMG-Compliance
1

Answer (score 0):

Is the info always in the same order? If so, you could break each section into a list and extract the data by something like:

```
OrgName = list[0]
Name = list[1]
.
.
.
```

Of course, this isn't exact, but just a thought.

Comment: It's not always in the order that the problem, most of the list is but there are a couple of section where there are additional comments too